# Why is my Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS 64bit going idle?

Tags: idle

I tend to run scripts for processing big datasets of 3D images and I find myself often surprised that during such operation, my computer just goes randomly idle, i.e., all the CPUs drop in activity and nothing happens anymore. To resume the processing operation, I found out that hitting the "ctrl" key does the trick. I also know that it has nothing to do with the sleep mode, as I deactivated it and I see that my monitor stays in operation, even when the CPUs drop.

My computer is running on Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS 64bit. GNOME 3.28.2, Graphics NV117. Processor: Intel Xeon (R) E5-2640 v4 @ 2.4Ghz.

Do you have any idea of how to avoid this behavior? Is it very inconvenient right now, as none of my batch jobs can run for a long period of time.

Thanks a lot for your help already!

Comment: Try doing `sudo do-release-upgrade` to upgrade your system. it seems to be a driver issue. And Ubuntu 22.10 includes a newer kernel, with newer drivers. Ubuntu 18.04 LTS will be EOL in early 2023.

Comment: Maybe not a sleep mode but it could be a powersaving mode. It might help to list your specs like processor, GPU, make and model, etc.

Comment: Can you exclude thermal problems while running your scripts?

Comment: You mean the computer getting too warm? The computer is currently located in a laboratory where the temperature is between 15 and 20 degrees Celsius, all year long. It is also not against a wall or something, so the fans operates properly.

Comment: I'd suggest applying all security updates/fixes asap, as if the details you provided are correct, you're more than a year behind on applying security fixes/patches.  Refer https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/09/17/ubuntu-18-04-6-lts-released/ though do note installed systems upgraded before that date as that date was the ISO release date only.